# Group Significant locations by date instead of location

Tags: ios, geolocation

I find the "Signficant locations" feature in IOS very useful.

(Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Service -> Significant Locations)

I will look through it when I do my time/billing as a reminder of where I've been.

However it groups the data by location, so if I want to find out where I was last Tuesday, I have to check every location in the list to try and see if that date is present.

Is there a 3rd party app that uses that very same data that groups it differently?

Comment: The answer on forensic search is going to be totally different than third party app recommendations and none of those will matter whether iOS had the feature built in. Is it ok if we edit out all the questions except one?

Comment: Can I break that out into another question? Possible on another subsite?

Comment: Yes please. Ask any single follow on question. Link here for context. Just think through what one answer is needed. Once you have three or four different answers on three or four questions, a synthesis question how to put them all together is most welcome. Just don’t start with a smorgasbord question is all we ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be changed and I don't know a way to retrieve this data.

There is an app that does this. [Find My Family, Friends, Phone.](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/find-my-family-friends-phone/id384830320?mt=8) Whilst the main use is family tracking it can be used to see location history. It offers 7 days history and 30 if you pay.

Another app that offers this is [Google Maps.](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/google-maps-transit-food/id585027354?mt=8) It offers a Your Time Line feature. You can see a history of each day. While not listing the places like iOS it is very similar.

Comment: The timeline feature of google maps seems like it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Aheho glad you found what you're looking for

Comment: Apple does not share the significant location data store with any third party app. You would need to opt in to google getting your location and then let it aggregate over time. Of course the location comes from iOS source for both, but the data set are not shared or transferable in either direction.